# sum of two arrays element wise?

Tags: java, arrays

There is a problem in which two random integer arrays are given, in which numbers from 0 to 9 are present at every index (i.e. single digit integer is present at every index of both given arrays). I need to find the sum of the numbers represented by the input arrays and put the result in another array.

I believe everything is fine with my code as I execute it almost 50 to 60 times for different arrays. But when I submit it in my school's online judge it accepted only 4 test cases and rejected the other two. I can't figure out in which case it will give wrong output. Need a little help guys.

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
public static int[] sumOfTwoArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    int size1 = arr1.length;
    int size2 = arr2.length;
    int carry = 0,sum,s,r;
    if(size1 == size2) {
        int arr3[] = new int[size1+1];
        for(int i=arr1.length-1;i>=-1;i--) { 
            if(i==-1) {
                arr3[i+1] = carry;
                //System.out.println(i+1+" "+arr3[i+1]);
            } else {
                sum = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
                if(sum>9) {
                    s =sum;
                    r = s % 10;
                    arr3[i+1] = carry + r;
                    carry = 1;
                    //System.out.println(i+" "+arr3[i]);    
                } else {
                    if(sum==9 && carry==1) {
                        s =sum+carry;
                        r = s % 10;
                        arr3[i+1] = r;
                    } else {
                        arr3[i+1] = sum+carry;
                        carry=0; 
                    }
                    //System.out.println(i+" "+arr3[i]);
                }  
            }      
        }
        return arr3;
    } else if (size1>size2) {
       int arr3[] = new int[size1+1];
       int diff = arr1.length - arr2.length;
       for(int i=arr1.length-1;i>=-1;i--) {
           if(i==-1) {
               arr3[i+1] = carry;
           } else {
               if(i>=diff) {
                   sum = arr1[i] + arr2[i-diff];
                    if(sum>9) {
                        s =sum;
                        r = s % 10;
                        arr3[i+1] = carry + r;
                        carry = 1;
                    } else {
                        if(sum==9 && carry==1) {
                            s =sum+carry;
                            r = s % 10;
                            arr3[i+1] = r;
                        } else {
                            arr3[i+1] = sum+carry;
                            carry=0; 
                        }
                    } 
                }  // end of diff i
                else {
                   arr3[i+1] =  arr1[i];
                   carry = 0;
                }
            }      
        }
        return arr3;
    } else {
        int arr3[] = new int[size2+1];
        int diff = arr2.length - arr1.length;
        for(int i=arr2.length-1;i>=-1;i--) {
            if(i==-1) {
                arr3[i+1] = carry;
            } else {
                if(i>=diff) {
                    sum = arr2[i] + arr1[i-diff];
                    if(sum>9) {
                        s =sum;
                        r = s % 10;
                        arr3[i+1] = carry + r;
                        carry = 1;
                    } else {
                        if(sum==9 && carry==1) {
                            s =sum+carry;
                            r = s % 10;
                            arr3[i+1] = r;
                        } else {
                            arr3[i+1] = sum+carry;
                            carry=0; 
                        }
                    }  
                }  // end of diff i
                else {
                    arr3[i+1] =  arr2[i];
                    carry = 0;
                }
            }      
        }
        return arr3;
    }   
}
```

Sample input:

```
int[] arr1 = {8,5,3,9,6};
int[] arr2 = {3,3,3,3,3};
```

Sample output:

```
{1,1,8,7,2,9}
```

Sample input:

```
int[] arr1 = {8,5,3,9,6};
int[] arr2 = {1,0,5};
```

Sample output:

```
{0,8,5,5,0,1}
```

Comment: This could contains some explanation on the algorithm, the input and output.

Comment: is that leading `0` in your last output really needed? shouldn't it be `{8,5,5,0,1}`?

Comment: @Roland You can't easily determine whether the result needs an extra digit or not for the carry, so I think OPs approach is okay.

Comment: Well, that is true somehow. but I rather want to know whether it is really needed or not? What if a test says, that no leading `0` is allowed?

Comment: @Roland Yes it is really needed. It was mentioned in my assignment

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap In my solution, I have added the reason of your bug.

Comment: I still find it too complicated. Is it allowed to transform the input beforehand? If so you might also want to look at [my proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41975042/6202869) and just do a simple sum. Only the condition for the leading `0` is missing, but that can also be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I have this algorith based on Eran solution (was working to fixe the bug he since corrected), I will shared it since I use less arrays.

```
public static int[] sum(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    int carry = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    int len1 = arr1.length;
    int len2 = arr2.length;
    int len = Math.max(len1, len2);

    int arr3[] = new int[len + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        sum =
            (len1 - i >= 0 ? arr1[len1-i] : 0)
            + (len2 - i >= 0 ? arr2[len2-i] : 0)
            + carry;

        arr3[len-i+1] = sum%10;
        carry = sum/10;
    }
    arr3[0] = carry;

    return arr3;
}
```

The usage of ternary operator is still readable so I find this a good solution.

For a short explanation, we read the arrays from the end, using `i` to read from right to left but based on the length of the arrays. The ternary operation is used in case of different array size.

EDIT :

Your algorithm doesn't manage correctly the carry value with different sized array.

`185 + 16` gives `101`.

Simply because you set the values like :

```
arr3[i+1] =  arr1[i];
```

So you forgot the carry that could occurs in the last operation.

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap, you are welcome. The reason was simply that you didn't test everything ;) you didn't had any test with different size AND carry at the end.

Comment: @AxelH yeah randomness is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

This code is way more complicated than it has to be, which increases the chances of it containing bugs hard to detect.

You don't have to implement the algorithm 3 times (based of whether the first array is smaller, larger or equal to the second array). You can implement it once for two equal sized arrays whose size is `Math.max(arr1.length,arr2.length)`.
That would eliminate 2/3 of your code.

```
int len = Math.max(arr1.length,arr2.length);
int[] arr11 = new int[len];
int[] arr22 = new int[len];
int arr3[] = new int[len+1];
for(int i=len-1;i>=-1;i--) {
    if (i>=len-arr1.length)
        arr11[i]=arr1[i-(len-arr1.length)];
    if (i>=len-arr2.length)
        arr22[i]=arr2[i-(len-arr2.length)];
    // now you can use arr11[i] and arr22[i] instead of arr1[i] and arr2[i]
    ...
}
```

Besides, instead of `sum = arr1[i] + arr2[i];` I suggest you add the carry immediately - `sum = arr11[i] + arr22[i] + carry;`. Now you only have to check once whether `sum > 9`.

```
    if(i==-1) {
        arr3[i+1] = carry;
    } else {
        sum = arr11[i] + arr22[i] + carry;
        if(sum>9) {
            arr3[i+1] = sum % 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            arr3[i+1] = sum;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
```

Combining the two snippets, you'll get :

```
int carry = 0;
int sum = 0;
int len = Math.max(arr1.length,arr2.length);
int[] arr11 = new int[len];
int[] arr22 = new int[len];
int arr3[] = new int[len+1];
for(int i=len-1;i>=-1;i--) {
    if(i==-1) {
        arr3[i+1] = carry;
    } else {
        if (i>=len-arr1.length)
            arr11[i]=arr1[i-(len-arr1.length)];
        if (i>=len-arr2.length)
            arr22[i]=arr2[i-(len-arr2.length)];
        sum = arr11[i] + arr22[i] + carry;
        if(sum>9) {
            arr3[i+1] = sum % 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            arr3[i+1] = sum;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
}
return arr3;
```

EDIT :

I had a small bug. I was adding 0s in the least significant digits of the smaller array (which are the high indices) instead of the most significant bits (the low indices), which made the result wrong if the arrays had different lengths. I fixed it, though now the part that copies the elements from the original arrays to `arr11` and `arr22` is less readable.

Comment: @Eran Tried it for `int arr1[] = {8, 5, 3, 9, 6};  int arr2[] = {1, 0, 5};` didn't work

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap Fixed now for arrays of differing lengths. Your input gives output `[0, 8, 5, 5, 0, 1]`.

Comment: @MauricePerry Fixed now.

Comment: @Eran yeah it works now but I still can't figure out what the heck is wrong with my lengthy code . It gives me right output every single time ఠ_ఠ

Comment: @Eran, well, I was writing mine and end up with this algo too. I just use `len1` and `len2` for readability. And simply put `arr3[0] = carry;` after the loop instead of this `if(i ==-1)`.

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap Your code is too long for me to analyze, sorry.

Comment: @AxelH Yeah, I just kept that `if(i ==-1)` from the OP's code.

Comment: @Eran, didn't remember that part. I've post my solution, based on yours (prior this bug fixe) so they vary a bit. But this seems a bit cleaner, less operation to get the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] firstArray = {1,8,8,8, 8};
        int[] secondArray = {1,8,9};
        String diffstring1 = "", diffstring2 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
            diffstring1 = diffstring1 + String.valueOf(firstArray[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++) {
            diffstring2 = diffstring2 + String.valueOf(secondArray[i]);
        }

        int diff = Integer.parseInt(diffstring1) + Integer.parseInt(diffstring2);

        String diifffinal = String.valueOf(diff);
        int[] third = new int[diifffinal.length()];
        for (int j = 0; j < diifffinal.length(); j++) {
            char abc = diifffinal.charAt(j);
            third[j] = Character.getNumericValue(abc);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:---> " + third[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If that leading `0` in your second sample output is not necessary, you can also use a different approach by transforming the input beforehand, e.g. with a function as follows:

```
static Integer toNumber(int[] arr) {
  return Integer.valueOf(Arrays.stream(arr)
                               .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                               .collect(Collectors.joining()));
}
```

That way you can just sum up your arrays as if they would be normal integers:

```
Integer sum = toNumber(arr1) + toNumber(arr2);
```

Transforming that back to an array can be done as follows:

```
int[] sumArray = sum.toString().chars()
                               .map(operand -> Character.digit(operand, 10))
                               .toArray();
```

But you don't have that leading `0` now in your output. That code uses Java 8, but the same is also writable without streams (but untested):

```
static Integer toNumber(int[] arr) {
  StringBuilder integerStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    integerStrBuilder.append(Integer.toString(arr[i]));
  }
  return Integer.valueOf(integerStrBuilder.toString());
}
```

and for the array:

```
char[] characters = sum.toString().toCharArray();
int[] sumArray = new int[characters.length];
for (int j = 0; j < characters.length; j++) {
  sumArray[j] = Characters.digit(characters[j], 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It kinda works

```
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, arr2 = {3, 5, 2, 9, 0};
        int[] output = new int[Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)];
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
        for (int value : arr1) {
            num1 = (num1 * 10) + value;
        }

        for (int i : arr2) {
            num2 = (num2 * 10) + i;
        }

        int result = (num1 + num2), k = output.length - 1;

        while(result > 0){
            output[k] = (result % 10);
            result = result / 10;
            k--;
        }

        if(k>0){
            output[k] = 0;
            k--;
        }

        for(int value: output){
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
    }
```